# Is it possible to receive SMS text messages on the computer?

Tags: windows, skype, google-talk, sms, google-voice

I do not have a mobile phone.  However, I would like to send and receive SMS text messages to friends' mobile phones using my computer (Windows) and the Internet.

Skype allows me to *send* SMS messages, but it does not — as far as I can tell — allow people to *send me* SMS messages (e.g., by responding to my SMS texts from Skype).

Is there some feature in Skype that I don't know about?  Or does Google Talk, Google Voice, or some other Windows-compatible software allow this?

Unfortunately, I do not have a mobile phone, so I cannot use services that reroute messages received on my (hypothetical) mobile phone to my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com) It uses the contact list in your Google Contacts. It also integrates into cell phones (iOS, Android) if you were to get one later.

Google Voice allows you to send/receive on a computer. The normal interface is a web interface, but I have standalone software for the Menubar on my mac, I assume there must be a Windows systray equivalent. You can even make calls from your computer, if you install the plugin and have a headset. Even if you don't use the headset, you can even "receive" calls with no phone - they'd leave you voicemail, and then you could listen to the VM from your computer (web interface or standalone app).

If you have Comcast **and** if you have their VoIP, you can SMS from their web interface as well. But I'd still go with the universality of Google Voice.

Comment: A web interface would be just as perfect; I was unclear about this in my original post.

Comment: On second thought, a web interface would be perfect *assuming* that it would receive messages even when I am not online/logged in.

Comment: @andrew Yes, they'd queue these up. You wouldn't miss them.

Comment: Looking at the Google Voice website, I'm very confused.  It seems like obtaining a Google phone number is *free*?  How can this be?

Comment: @andrew yes it is free. Google bought Grandcentral a while ago. Google is worried about the world going mobile/cellphone and the desktop/web will be deemphasized. Android for free is one consequence of this. Google Voice the other.

Comment: @andrew RE: why is GVoice free?  Just saw this - [mobile vs search](http://www.slashgear.com/google-q2-2012-mobile-is-where-search-was-in-1999-19239452/)

Comment: Last I checked you have to have a mobile phone in order to sign up for Google Voice, so I'm not sure why this has been accepted as an answer.

Comment: @LayneBernardo last I signed up you need a phone not necessarily a cell phone. If this has changed then yes GV won’t work

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of landlines actually. That's a good point.