# Is it possible to plug a mobile SIM card into a (non smartphone) computer and use it to send/receive text messages? Not Google Voice VoIP

Tags: usb, sim

Is it possible to plug a mobile SIM card into a computer and use it to send/receive text messages?

I have seen [Is it possible to receive SMS text messages on the computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/451114/is-it-possible-to-receive-sms-text-messages-on-the-computer)  But they accept google voice as a solution, and I am interested specifically in as i've asked.

I've seen this question [Can a SIM card reader be used to access mobile data? As in, use 4G/mobile broadband?](https://superuser.com/questions/1699590/can-we-use-a-sim-card-reader-and-access-the-sims-mobile-data)  It mentions LTE adaptors, though that doesn't mention text messages.

Comment: this thing mentions something though it's programmable so maybe requires some configuring  https://www.selectiveintellect.net/blog/2021/8/19/setting-up-sms-sending-and-receiving-using-a-usb-gsm-dongle-by-zte   This link mentions a device though maybe requires flashing https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/lpur29/is_there_an_usb_dongle_which_allows_you_to/ .. also https://gist.github.com/ethaniel/d7f9c3192041c64c89d2c5b49527d0e2 though that's linux

Comment: The issue is while SIM adapters work, they are — to the best of my knowledge — data only and are effectively mini hotspots not too dissimilar to the mobile hotspots that use SIMs for connectivity. Meaning a mobile hotspot will typically be Wi-Fi only. But a USB version of a “hot spot” would be USB data connectivity only. While text/SMS messages are indeed data, to the best of my knowledge text/SMS messages need an actual phone number to send/receive text/SMS data.

Comment: Its a bit messy - I've seen it done over a specific client. The LTE adaptor I have (some random aliexpress one that's basically a screenless android phone with a webui) won't work directly on windows 11, cause I have no idea what the driver is, but can connect to linux.... so OS might matter.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 well whether it supports a hotspot or not is secondary.. (And by the way I have seen usb adaptors that don't take a sim card, but can switch between acting as a wireless client - connecting to WiFi, or act as a wireless access point /hotspot.. so in theory there's nothing about usb that prevents it from being a hotspot.. anyhow i'm not caring much re whether it does hotspot or not)

Comment: @barlop You completely missed my point. I am not saying that these USB adapters are mobile hotspots. But from a technical point of view they are _similar_ to them. In the case of a mobile hotspot, the SIM is used in conjunction with a router that is a part of the hotspot. In the case of these USB adapters, the USB adapter is not a router but effectively _just_ a data modem that connects to a USB port and is seen as a modem by the system.  Again, without a phone number I don’t believe text/SMS stuff would work at all.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 well, you may be onto something in that I have seen a sim card in a router/modem and the router/modem didn't show the mobile number associated with the sim card.  Maybe the stick needs particular technology for texts and they tend not to have it. Perhaps GSM technology seems some might have it

Comment: @Giacomo1968 what about something like this https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/363150419273 "USB Cellphone SIM Card Reader SMS Copy/Cloner/Writer/Backup GSM/CDMA+CD Driver"

Comment: @barlop Maybe. But in my experience these USB SIM card modems are mainly sold in — for lack of a better term — poorer countries where having things like a static cable modem and such are not practical. So people buy these things and use SIM cards for connectivity. And since mobile carriers can control what SIM cards they will allow on their network — and what devices can use those SIM cards — the chances of you doing what you describe if you are _not_ in a country with mobile providers who support this is pretty much zero percent.

Comment: @barlop Nope. That won’t work. That is self-described as a “USB Cellphone SIM Card Reader SMS Copy/Cloner/Writer/Backup GSM/CDMA+CD Driver” Note the word “modem” is never used? All that does is read the data on a SIM card. Much like an SD card reader only reads data on an SD card. It does not have the modem inside of it to connect to a cell provider’s tower. It even clearly states, “Read, edit, backup your telephone directory and SMS for your GSM devices. Allows you to copy different number to one sim card, including phone book, SMS, ring tones, photos, etc.”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138336/discussion-between-barlop-and-giacomo1968).

Comment: Voting to close because the other two questions linked to already clearly answer the issue: The reality is a USB SIM card reader can only read (and write?) to SIM cards with proper software. And there are indeed USB SIM modems that work for data… Not not all the time and not in a way that would allow SMS/text messaging. Many of these USB SIM modems are just getting power from the PC it connects to and are effectively tiny mobile hotspots. And past any of that, many cell phone providers do not allow such devices to connect to their cell tower networks. The other questions already answer this.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 the  other questions  don't cover it. One accepts google voice. The other doesnt mention sms

Comment: I believe that between these comments and text in chat I explained as much as I can. As for why the other questions cover it, sorry but this question adds nothing new. Done here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 All i'm trying to explain to you is that the other questions  aren't looking for what I ask for here. That doesn't mean your comments here don't address the question, or that you can say more than you have.

Comment: HP hs3110 (which is rebranded Huawei MU736) can send and receive SMS on Windows (and maybe on Linux too, but I couldn't find the right software). For receiving Windows the built-in Messaging is enough, for sending eg. [this](http://awx.black-it.eu/en/software/mobile%20broadband%20sms%20toolkit/index.htm) works. It's an old modem with some problems though, I can't recommend it.

Comment: I've done this a long time ago - I don't know how if it can be done on new network technologies.  If your network supports it you can get a USB GSM modem, and then send it AT commands to send SMS messages. (Googling GSM modem send SMS will come up with quite a few answers)

Comment: A SIM has the authentication system.  It does not have a transmitter or receiver, it can't send anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Things you will need:

- Carrier Sim Card (Verizon, ATT, ETC...)
- WWAN Card compatible with carrier SIM
- Software to communicate with WWAN Card and Sim

Take a look at the `smstools`, `ppp`, and `gnokii` software packages available on GNU/Linux and the BSDs (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD). I am currently working on a project integrating a phone system with a pc, gnokii and smstools work well sending/receving sms, mms. have not tried calling though

Some examples I have been able to find that helped me are

#### -- SMS TEXTING OVER 4G USING SMSTOOLS --

This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv5zYfwl0wk  Titled  "Raspberry Pi SMS And Mobile Internet"  By Tall Paul Tech  And refers to https://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/sierra_advanced

#### -- CONFIGURING A WWAN CARD ON UNIX LIKE SYSTEM --

This video  titled
"The 4G LTE Raspberry Pi Router has arrived! // OpenWrt, Verizon Network"  By  Dev Odyssey

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4KlUKDai04&t=761s

###### WWAN configuration is heavily dependent on SIM Carrier, WWAN Card in use, and OS in use - Consult your Operating System manual pages for exact information

#### -- MANUAL PAGES FOR MENTIONED TOOLS --

Debian man page for `smstools` - https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/smstools/smsd.8.en.html

FreeBSD man page for `ppp` - https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ppp&sektion=8

linux.die.net man page for `gnokii` - https://linux.die.net/man/1/gnokii

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1216107)

Comment: Very informative.  I guess with a WWAN USB adaptor or even WWAN slotting into the motherboard,  it wouldn't matter if a motherboard supports WWAN?  'cos the receiving/transmitting is done from the card not from the MBRD.  Just like if an old computer has no WiFi client support, so can't connect to a wireless router, but you can put a WiFi card in there and then connect it to a wireless router. Or if a laptop or desktop doesnt have an ethernet/RJ45 socket, you can get a USB-Ethernet adaptor , or on an old desktop you can get a PCI Ethernet card if a PC didn't have an ethernet/RJ45 socket.

Comment: So WWAN is mobile internet? And a WWAN adaptor provides favility to send/receive. But it has to be compatible with the SIM.

Comment: @barlop That is correct! If you take a look at the first video (Raspberry Pi SMS And Mobile Internet - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv5zYfwl0wk) HE uses a USB 4g WWAN card connected to a raspberry pi used as a router for access from any pc on the network!

Comment: @barlop I noticed you have been in the comments since 2022, so I hope I was able to provide some new information to feed on! :)

Comment: Well you've helped clarify some concepts in my mind.. And your info helps anybody looking this up not just me asking the question.  Good stuff. Thanks. Can you clarify  why the necessity of "Motherboard supporting WWAN 3G/4G/5G functionality" ?  If it supports that functionality then why would you need a WWAN card?

Comment: @barlop By "Motherboard supporting WWAN 3g/4g/5g functionality" I mean the system has either 3g/4g/5g antennas and supports the use of a WWAN card in the Mini PCI-E slot.

Most all boards now come with a Mini PCI-E slot, but its up to the manufacturer to include the support for WWAN and not just WLAN.

Likewise and similar to a cell phone, the system also has to have an antenna somewhere to 'grab' a signal, usually they run somewhere behind the display in the bezel, just like an iphones antenna runs along the top of the device.

Comment: @Destroy666 I apologize I seem to have missed your comment. Can you please clarify what you are referring too? I am unsure what you mean by 'While this link may answer the question it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.' , there is multiple links and references, as this is a multi-step configuration. Are you recommending listing all steps covered in linked videos? The question also only refers to 'is it possible' not 'provide a guide to achieve'

Comment: This is basically an automated message when requesting deletion of link-only answers. This network doesn't like them - you should be at least partially explaining each of the link, in case they disppear in the future. And the only thing except them in your answer is a list of needed things, which doesn't really answer the question alone.

Comment: @KLD997 Thanks. I suppose if it's a desktop then the card could come with an antenna. But even on a laptop the card could include an internal antenna couldn't it?  Is a WWAN antenna different to a WLAN antenna?

Comment: @barlop I have misinformed you a bit upon a little more looking, WWAN does not utilize Mini PCI-E, but M.2 2242. Correct for the internal antenna coming included. An example is my Thinkpad T520i, I utilize both WLAN using Mini PCI-E on a 3 pin antenna, and WWAN using M.2 2242 Sierra Wireless EM7511 card on a  2 pin antenna. Im assuming you could swap the antenna's on WLAN and WWAN, but both operate at different frequencies. WLAN operates on your standard 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz, while WWAN encompasses multiple frequencies covering the major carriers.

Comment: @barlop I however am not familiar enough with radio and frequencies to decide for certain if you can swap between antenna's, that is a whole monster on its own! :)

Comment: @KLD997 so if the antennas are internal to the card then I guess MBRD compatibility is irrelevant? The motharboard just has to have the controller-socket  used by the WWAN adaptor.  If the WWAN adaptor were USB you could just plug it into the USB controller-socket.

Comment: @KLD997 You could remove/replace this line "Motherboard supporting WWAN 3G/4G/5G functionality" because it's not correct since with USB you don't need a motherboard supporting WWAN. .Or even aside from USB, as mentioned, if there's a slot for the card and the card has an internal antenna, then it'll work.

Comment: @barlop Removed the "Motherboard supporting WWAN 3G/4G/5G functionality" from things needed, I also converted it to a community wiki so others can add additional routes to achieve the goal!